# Download different content types with spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to expose a POST endpoint where the user uploads an excel file and based on some validations, I either send back the file with some information added to it along with json response OR just send status code as 200 OK(no data).
I am trying to do this in spring boot. I tried following link:
https://javadigest.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/downloading-multiple-files-using-multipart-response/

This works but needs adding boundary manually. Is there any other way to do it so that I can send both the data ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use @Produces as it is written here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ghrpv/index.html

You can define the MIME-Type of your payload.